# How could i solve this with Prolog?

Tags: prolog

i have list in prolog for example `L=[a,b,c,d,e,f]` , i want to convert this list to new list that has this type `L2=[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]`, in other words, i want to convert every two consecutive element in the list to new list.

Answer (score 3):

the plain Prolog, tailored on your requirements:

```
'convert every two consecutive element'([], []). % base case
'convert every two consecutive element'([A,B|R], [[A,B]|S]) :-
  'convert every two consecutive element'(R, S).
```

The list length must be even for this to succeed, otherwise you will need to refine the base case.

Comment: for odd lists:
'convert every two consecutive element'([A], [])

Comment: @GuillermoMerino that would delete the last element of an odd parity list. The OP didn't define what they want to do with an odd element, but perhaps a logical thing to do would be to include it as a single element sublist, `[A]`. So the additional base case would be, `'convert every two consecutive element'([A], [[A]]).` Then, `'convert every two consecutive element'([a,b,c,d,e], L).` would yield, `L = [[a,b],[c,d],[e]]` instead of `[[a,b],[c,d]]`.